# Nomad HTTP health check does not seem to occur

Tags: nomad

It seems the HTTP health check is not occurring, I've come to this conclusion due to the HTTP debug log not showing any regular periodic requests.

Is there any additional configuration request for a health check to occur?

```
job "example" {

  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"


  update {
    max_parallel = 1
    min_healthy_time = "10s"
    healthy_deadline = "3m"
    progress_deadline = "10m"
    auto_revert = false
    canary = 0
  }

  migrate {
    max_parallel = 1
    health_check = "checks"
    min_healthy_time = "10s"
    healthy_deadline = "5m"
  }

  group "app" {
    count = 1

    restart {
      attempts = 2
      interval = "30m"

      delay = "15s"

      mode = "fail"
    }

    ephemeral_disk {

      size = 300
    }

    task "app" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "localhost:5000/myhub:latest"
        command = "python"
        args = [
          "manage.py",
          "runserver",
          "0.0.0.0:8001"
        ]

        port_map {
          app = 8001
        }
        network_mode = "host"
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 500
        memory = 256
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "app" {}
        }
      }

      service {
        name = "myhub"
        port = "app"
        check {
          name     = "alive"
          type     = "http"
          port     = "app"
          path     = "/"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout  = "3s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Consul must be installed for this to occur.

Also make sure to install Consul v1.4.2 or later as v1.4.1 seems to have a bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/5270